# Merging mp3s into one in Python

Tags: python, mp3, pydub

I have read on SOverflow to use PyDub for this, but PyDub doesn't seem to be working in Python 3.9. This is my code

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
firstfile = AudioSegment.from_mp3(r'C:/Users/ogiga/Desktop/Nice/FinalVideo.mp3')
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Neither one of these work:

```
r'C:\Users\ogiga\Desktop\Nice\FinalVideo.mp3'
r'C:/Users/ogiga/Desktop/Nice/FinalVideo.mp3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downloaded proper FFMPEG, added it to Path. It didn't work, but I restarted my PC and it worked.